# Where does Weblogic upload webapp in AdminServer?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, deployment, location, weblogic

I deployed a webapp on Weblogic from Eclipse(right click on project -> Run As -> Run on Server). It is deployed successfully and is accessible correctly. I want to know location of it so, from console I tried:

1. Deployments -> selected deployment -> Overview -> 'Path' shows: "[project-location]. metadata\ . plugins\ org. eclipse. wst.
   server. core\ tmp0\ base_domain\ _auto_generated_ear_"(though I deployed a webapp). But, there's
   neither exploded directory nor compressed file in that location.
2. Environment -> Servers -> AdminServer -> Configuration -> Deployment -> Upload Directory Name" shows: ".\servers\AdminServer\upload" as value. But, there's no 'upload' directory under AdminServer, in file system. I re-checked path for correctness, and I did check in correct path.

So, where is the server uploading exploded directory or compressed file?

**Environment:**

1. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
2. Weblogic 12c with only admin server, no managed servers.
3. Windows 10

Comment: Try: WL_INSATLL_DIR\user_projects\domains\YOUR_DOMAIN\servers\AdminServer\tmp

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev I checked there, domains folder is empty. Probably, because, I had configured the domain in question. I didn't mention specifically, as I thought it was obvious.

Comment: When you create a server in eclipse you are asked to set the domain, so your deployment must be there.